# How can I install mongodb on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-21.04

I followed official guide to install, but I got below error, when I check for status.

```
Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since
```

Comment: > when I check for status ?
how did you check the status ?

Comment: @RahulDahal    "sudo systemctl status mongod"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74153635/hi-i-tried-to-install-but-failed-mongodb-but-something-went-worng-i-was-try-to (for Johannes Barop answer)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me!

```bash
curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | \
    sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb.asc > /dev/null
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | \
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Comment: Beware of the "sudo apt-get upgrade" it might wreck your distro!

Answer (score 2):

First remove previously installed files related to Mongodb

```bash
sudo service mongod stop 
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org* 
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb 
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

After multiple install and uninstall I found the issue, with official guide, as of 13/08/2021 it does not have information on 21.04, but if you check in the command their only one thing is changing that is codename, 20.04 has focal, 18.04 bionic same way 21.04 has "hirsute" [image]

you can check this by typing in terminal "lsb_release -dc"

[image]

command with correct codename

```bash
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu hirsute/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

run the able commands in order.

Comment: interesting. This didn't work for me. If you just point the browser to https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu, then you will see `dist/hirsute` is clearly missing.
Installing the focal one did work for me on lubuntu 21.04

Comment: This won't work. The OP clearly mentions Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 0):

I installed like Harish suggested but left it with Focal when creating the apt source list instead of Hirsute.
Got same error as OP.
Looked at /var/log/mongodb, noticed no mongod.log had been created so I created mongod.log file under /var/log/mongodb, then changed the owner to mongodb for mongod.log, restarted the service for mongod and it worked.

```
sudo touch /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
sudo systemctl restart mongod.service
sudo systemctl status mongod.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can follow the [installation guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) for 20.04, except for *Step 1 - Import Public Key* use the following instead:

`wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb.asc > /dev/null`