# Hi,I tried to install but failed MongoDB, BUT something went worng, i was try to fix it, but it didn't work

Tags: linux, mongodb, linux-mint

***Linux MInt 21***, I try to instal MongoDB for like 3 days but apparently I'm not doing something right. I would greatly appreciate it if you could tell me what I am doing wrong :)) I post what i did in the terminal, I removed it and install it again but and that went wrong too

```
Lenovo-Y520-15IKBM:~$ sudo apt install mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate

Lenovo-Y520-15IKBM:~$ ^C

Lenovo-Y520-15IKBM:~$ sudo apt-get purge mongo*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mongodb-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-dev' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongoose' for glob 'mongo*'
Package 'mongodb-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongoose' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 63 not upgraded.

Lenovo-Y520-15IKBM:~$ sudo apt install mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate

Lenovo-Y520-15IKBM:~$ ^C

Lenovo-Y520-15IKBM:~$ sudo apt remove --autoremove mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
Lenovo-Y520-15IKBM:~$ ^C

Lenovo-Y520-15IKBM:~$ sudo apt install mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candi
```

Answer (score 2):

A Linux Mint release is always based on a specific Ubuntu version. When you add the MongoDB repositories, you must make sure to reference the correct Ubuntu version. The corresponding variant of Ubuntu is specified in `/etc/os-release`.

Here is an example for installing MongoDB-6 in Mint

```
curl -sS https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-6.0.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor --output /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb-org-6.0-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release; echo "$UBUNTU_CODENAME")/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 0):

the new command for the curl to work should be:
`curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | \ sudo gpg -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg \ --dearmor`

Answer (score -1):

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list

sudo apt-get update


sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

try these commands and you will have mongodb installed on mint

do not forget to start mongodb `sudo systemctl start mongod`

Comment: This won't work because of dependency problems. Mint 21 is based on Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) and you're trying to install MongoDB version for Ubuntu 20.04 (focal). The consequence are dependency problems. Also, `apt-key` is deprecated and should not be used anymore.